# Return Data based Relevant Dates

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have an occupancy table and a pay history table. I want to return the state that the employee is in from the occupancy at the time of the relevant pay.

Occupancy Table

```
 Emp#|Commence Date|State
-----|-------------|----
 101 |  1/01/2016  | VIC
 101 |  1/04/2016  | NSW
 101 |  1/08/2016  | ACT
```

Pay History Table

```
 Emp#|Pay Date
 ----|--------
 101 |15/01/2016
 101 |15/02/2016
 101 |15/03/2016
 101 |15/04/2016
 101 |15/05/2016
 101 |15/06/2016
 101 |15/07/2016
 101 |15/08/2016 
 101 |15/09/2016
```

I'm wanting to return the following

```
 Emp#|:Pay Date:|State
 ----|----------|-----
 101 |15/01/2016|VIC
 101 |15/02/2016|VIC
 101 |15/03/2016|VIC
 101 |15/04/2016|NSW
 101 |15/05/2016|NSW
 101 |15/06/2016|NSW
 101 |15/07/2016|NSW
 101 |15/08/2016|ACT 
 101 |15/09/2016|ACT
```

Can someone assist, please

Comment: Did you try writing the query? if so could you post your effort and let us know on what issue you are facing? Or do you need the ideas to write this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate the `end_date` in the `occupancy` table in a subquery; the `lead()` function is perfect for this purpose. I use it with all three arguments - the third argument gives a "default" date which I chose arbitrarily as 15 December 2099 for the "current" status. Then its a simple join on `empno` and a `between` condition on dates.

I assume you have more than one `empno` in your data, so I accommodated that. Then: I don't know if # is legal in Oracle column names, but I didn't want to try; I changed to `empno`. And names definitely can't have spaces in them unless you quote the names, which has many disadvantages; I worked around that too.

```
with
     occupancy ( empno, commence_date, state ) as (
       select 101, to_date('1/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'VIC' from dual union all
       select 101, to_date('1/04/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'NSW' from dual union all
       select 101, to_date('1/08/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'ACT' from dual
     ),
     pay_history ( empno, pay_date ) as (
       select 101, to_date('15/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
       select 101, to_date('15/02/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
       select 101, to_date('15/03/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
       select 101, to_date('15/04/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
       select 101, to_date('15/05/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
       select 101, to_date('15/06/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
       select 101, to_date('15/07/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
       select 101, to_date('15/08/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
       select 101, to_date('15/09/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual
     )
-- end of test data (not part of the SQL query); query begins below this line
select p.empno, p.pay_date, o.state
from   pay_history p inner join (
         select empno, commence_date,
                lead(commence_date, 1, date '2099-12-15') 
                    over (partition by empno order by commence_date) as end_date,
                state
         from   occupancy ) o
            on  p.empno = o.empno 
            and p.pay_date between o.commence_date and o.end_date
order by empno, pay_date    --   if needed
;
```

**Output**:

```
EMPNO PAY_DATE   STATE
----- ---------- -----
  101 15/01/2016 VIC
  101 15/02/2016 VIC
  101 15/03/2016 VIC
  101 15/04/2016 NSW
  101 15/05/2016 NSW
  101 15/06/2016 NSW
  101 15/07/2016 NSW
  101 15/08/2016 ACT
  101 15/09/2016 ACT

9 rows selected.
```

Comment: Thanks mathguy. This worked a treat. You're correct, I have about 10,000 employees and numerous other fields but simplified the example.

Comment: @Enauf - you may want to take a look at the other answer I just posted; it may be more efficient than this one. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Negotiating against myself here :-)  I am posting this as a separate Answer, rather than editing my earlier one, because this is indeed a different answer.

Please refer to my other Answer for the input data and sample output - they are the same. Only the query is different. Instead of a join, we can UNION ALL the two tables (with some necessary adjustments: add a `null` column for `state` to the `pay_history` table, and a `flag` of `0` for the `occupancy` table and `1` for the `pay_history` table); then use the `last_value()` analytic function on the resulting union, and filter out the rows from the `occupancy` table in the outermost query. This may be quite a bit faster than the join-based solution.

```
select   empno, dt as pay_date, state
from     (
           select empno, dt, flag,
                  last_value(state ignore nulls) 
                             over (partition by empno order by dt, flag) as state
           from   (
                    select empno, commence_date as dt, state, 0 as flag
                      from occupancy
                    union all
                    select empno, pay_date, null, 1
                      from pay_history
                  )
         )
where    flag = 1
order by empno, pay_date   --  if needed
;
```